# throwing access denied error in azure migrate appliance while adding server during discovery and assessment

Tags: azure, cloud, server-migration

I am trying to migrate AWS EC2 instance (created via my personal id) to Azure (comes under my office subscription) via Azure Migrate.

Here is the issue:

I keep getting access is denied error message on the Azure Migrate appliance. I have entered the physical server details and IP address but still failing. added a screenshot for reference.

May I know how would I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please allow the windows remote management http-in and in public profile double click and check the scope of rule it should be selected as remote ip address to ANY the issue will get resolved and also make sure that you are adding ip address of same machine and credentials also of the same machine.